# cannot read property 'variable' of undefined when creating a Telegram bot

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm sure you all faced that problem, but if any could help I'll be glad.
I'm REALLY sure no errors in my code are written.
I'm trying to make a bot that send lyrics, however a JSON file is being returned. When I try to print WHATEVER statement from the file it throws the above error.
Here's the code:

```
const Genius = require("node-genius");
const geniusClient = new Genius('some API');

geniusClient.search('blank space', function gotData(err, data){
    console.log(data.meta.status);
});
```

The output JSON file have SO many branches, but here's the meta part which I don't really need but just for the sake of simplicity.

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": 200
    },
    "response": {
        "hits": [
            {
                "highlights": [],
                "index": "song",
                "type": "song",
                "result": {
                    "annotation_count": 27,
                     stuff..........stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an string, try converting it to an object with `JSON.parse()`:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(obj.meta.status);
```

Comment: You just saved me dude... A BIG THANK YOU!!